# How to print the entered details of form in new page?

Tags: magento-1.8

I had created the new form with the details name,gender,date of birth
and email id.
I am attaching the image what i had created these details had to print with the filled information of the customer when i click on the generate button

I need to print these details on my new page.Can anyone please suggest me

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your question is incomplete and so is my answer to your question:

In your controller (for example `saveAction()` you can access variables via:

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
```

or

```
$emailAddress = $this->getRequest()->getPost('email_address');
```

Comment: When I click on generate button it redirects to new page.On that page the form details has to be printed.

Comment: Without adding any code to your question it will be hard to suggest anything for a solution.